# Bitcoin mining with cloud

Tags: cloud-mining

Where is cloud mining ok? many companies dont let you use their cloud to mine bitcoin so how do you do cloud mining? And is cloud mining worth it and does cloud mining have more advantages than normal mining?

Comment: Apart from things shared by Pieter Wuille, would add one more thing: Cloud mining term is mostly associated with websites and companies that are scammers who either use your funds in trading or create a [ponzi scheme](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponzi_scheme) that looks legit.

Comment: @Prayank I agree, though I don't think that's what OP is asking about (it sounds like literally using some compute cloud to run mining on, not companies offering "cloud mining" as a concept directly).

Comment: @Pieter Wuille yeah I was not talking about companies doing it.

Comment: I understand its different. Reason I commented this is: 1. People searching "cloud mining" on stackexchange or google and reading this 2. Scammers using this link to justify cloud mining is legit just needs ASIC. I have tried experimenting node and mining both on cloud (Google, Azure) in past and VMs were banned based on algos.

Comment: @Prayank Absolutely, I upvoted it too, because it's useful for people looking for related information. I commented to avoid letting OP think it was an answer to their question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitcoin is mined using chips specifically produced for the purpose of SHA256 mining (ASICs). Anything else is an pointless waste of electricity and hardware, and will cost you orders of magnitude more than the gains.

Using clouds does not change this. Even if companies allowed it, it would cost you more than what it earns you.

You need ASICs.